# Missing compiler required member but have already added Microsoft.CSharp package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to run a Xamarin.Forms application where the `.Core` project is `.NET Standard 2.0`. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and this is the first time I've run a Xamarin solution.

The `nnn.Core` project does not build and gives a series of identical compilation errors

> CS0656    Missing compiler required member
> 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

When I first ran into this error, I did some searching and discovered [this post](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/net-core-standard-missing-compiler-required-member) which states

> To fix it I had to include I just had to include Microsoft.CSharp from
> Nuget.

So, I opened the project's `.csproj` file, which is the file containing the line

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

I found the `ItemGroup` containing the `PackageReference` elements, so added

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
```

Rebuilding the solution took the number of errors from ~9 to 4, but the same errors persist. What's strange is that they are just a subset of the original errors, as if only some lines in the `.Core` project were fixed by the package inclusion, and some were not. Yet, all the lines throwing the build error are in the same project.

The first line throwing the build error above is the assignment to a `dymamic` property (second line):

```
dynamic values = new JObject();
values.LANGUAGE = _localize.GetCurrentCultureInfo().TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToUpper();
```

In fact, all the lines still throwing the error are the first line following the creation of a `dynamic` object, where a property is assigned.

What am I missing to fix this?

**EDIT**

Specifically, the Android project has a `packages.config` file which contains

```
<package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
```

The iOS project's `packages.config` file also has

```
<package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

Comment: Close and reopen Visual Studio. If still broken, close solution, delete all .bin and .obj folders. Try again. If still broken, I see MANY links on this topic, when google `CS0656 Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'`. See if you can find additional suggestions.

Comment: @toolmakersteve Please post your comment as an answer and I can accept it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Close and reopen Visual Studio.
- If still broken, close solution, delete all .bin and .obj folders. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

A Xamarin.Forms project has not only one .csproj file. For the share part which you have been added the nuget package `Microsoft.CSharp` into.

For the other platforms' part, such as `YourProjecName.Android`, `YourProjecName.iOS` and `YourProjecName.UWP` part. You can try the steps below to add the nuget package `Microsoft.CSharp`.

Right click on the platform part project-> Select the Unload the project->Double click the platform part project-> Add the `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />`

Comment: See my edit in the post

Comment: Does the similar error appear if you create a new xamarin.forms project and use the `dynamic` in it? And you can use the Nuget Package Manager to download the `Microsoft.CSharp` in each part of the project by yourself. @MattW

Comment: Have not checked - comment by @toolmakersteve solved my problem.

Comment: All right, happy coding. @MattW